# Checking value of DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` where a column is `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`. How can I check whether the `CheckBox` inside of a cell of the column is checked?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439758/how-to-know-a-specific-checkbox-inside-datagridview-is-checked-or-not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
        bool status=(bool)dataGridView3.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value;
        if (status)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Checked");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not Checked");
        }
```